# Issue with React-Boostrap's Offcanvas and breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to implement an offcanvas style navbar using react-boostrap, and am trying to make it responsive so that menu icon disappears and the contents are displayed on the nav bar itself when the screen reaches above a certain size.

I used the example from their site but have changed the value of the expand property and added a collapse component: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navbar/#navbar-offcanvas

```
import {
  Navbar,
  Container,
  Offcanvas,
  NavDropdown,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  Button,
  Nav,
} from "react-bootstrap";

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="1g" collapseOnSelect>
      <Container fluid>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#">Navbar Offcanvas</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="offcanvasNavbar">
          <Navbar.Offcanvas
            id="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
            placement="end"
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              <Offcanvas.Title id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                Offcanvas
              </Offcanvas.Title>
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <Nav.Link href="#action1">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#action2">Link</Nav.Link>
                <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="offcanvasNavbarDropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action3">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action4">
                    Another action
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Divider />
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action5">
                    Something else here
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </Nav>
              <Form className="d-flex">
                <FormControl
                  type="search"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  className="me-2"
                  aria-label="Search"
                />
                <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
              </Form>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

The menu icon should disappear and the contents expand onto the navbar at 992 horizontal res, but nothing changes.

I also tried to use a normal navbar from their examples, but then replace the body with an offcanvas body like so:

```
<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="light">
  <Container>
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
    <Navbar.Offcanvas
            id="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
            placement="end"
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              <Offcanvas.Title id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                Offcanvas
              </Offcanvas.Title>
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <Nav.Link href="#action1">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#action2">Link</Nav.Link>
                <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="offcanvasNavbarDropdown">
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action3">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action4">
                    Another action
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Divider />
                  <NavDropdown.Item href="#action5">
                    Something else here
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </Nav>
              <Form className="d-flex">
                <FormControl
                  type="search"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  className="me-2"
                  aria-label="Search"
                />
                <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
              </Form>
            </Offcanvas.Body>
          </Navbar.Offcanvas>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
```

And while this did actually make the icon disappear correctly, none of the menu's contents would appear onto the bar as they are supposed to.

I've been taking bits out and putting bits in for long enough now that I could have probably created my own by now haha, but I really want to figure out what it is I'm missing.

Any help would be amazing!